# Angular js how to play a video (video player)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, video-player

Below on my HTML code that is how i loaded pdf and image documents and it seem to work. But I cant seem to load ang play a video? it does not work, is there a directive for that ? do i need a player for that ? Any idea would really be a help. I know this is not about code debugging guys but i do hope you understand. Also I already have a feature to upload and call the video , the problem is I dont know the feature how to have a preview or a player for it. Thank you.

```
<div class="col-md-12 top10">

<img ng-class="{'hidden' : main.record.preview.type != 'image'}"
     style="width: 100%" class="img"
     src="{$ main.record.preview.preview $}">

<object ng-class="{'hidden' : main.record.preview.type != 'pdf'}"
        ng-show="(main.record.preview.preview != undefined || main.record.preview.preview != '') && main.record.preview.type == 'pdf"
        data="{$ main.record.preview.preview | trusted $}" style="width: 100%;height: 800px"
        data="{$ main.record.preview.preview | trusted $}" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="{$ main.record.preview.preview | trusted $}" type="application/pdf" />
</object>


<div ng-show="main.record.preview.type == 'others'"
     class="col-md-12 text-center text-default no-preview">
    <p><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> No Preview Available</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Read [MDN Video Tutorial - `<video>` Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content#The_%3Cvideo%3E_element).

Answer (score 2):

`<video>` tag should get this going... something along the lines below...

```html
<div ng-show="main.record.preview.type == 'video'" class="col-md-12 text-center text-default no-preview">
  <video  controls>
  <source src="yourVideoLink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> No Preview Available</p>
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: How about the file is from local folder?

Comment: `src="{{yourVariableWithVideoFile}}"` or `src="/relativeFileLocation"`

Comment: yeah i did that but it seem not to work src="/home/dev/Documents/HRIS/hris_api_copy/v1/storage/6/documents/Resumes and Applications/46661-small.mp4"

Comment: are you getting an error? when you open this mp4 URL in browser, you get the video, and no 404 error, right?

Comment: let me replicate this and get back to you

Comment: bro can you visit this link ? how can we make this one to play a local video file ?

Comment: or how can we add the {$ main.record.preview.preview $} to the source cause it uses videos array of objects

Comment: @JhonCaylog **(1)** For local file try as...  `src="file:///home/dev/Documents/HRIS/hris_api_copy/v1/storage/6/documents/Resumes and Applications/46661-small.mp4"` ... **(2)** Those spaces might cause problems (since spaces in a URL are not allowed) so if still not working then add `%20` where a space should be... _eg:_ `Resumes%20and%20Applications`